# Localization error of App in ios

Tags: ios, localization, internationalization

I've followed all the desired steps to achieve localization of application.following are those steps:

1. create a `Localizable.strings` file.
2. add languages which we are looking to localized.
3. add these in `localizable.strings` using add localized button.

Now I'm getting following alert message :

> fatal: index file smaller than expected"

along with this the `Localizable.strings` file is not appearing in the list which asks about the reference file and resource language.anybody please help me as soon as possible.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you describe what you do in step 2?

Comment: Where does the alert shows? Googling the error seams only to report some git issues that you can actually solve with the solution Tuân gave you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be like a git error which can be fixed by removing `.git/index` and then reset to HEAD.
You can find details here:
http://programertools.blogspot.com/2014/04/how-to-fix-fatal-index-file-smaller.html

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this [Localization link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial) .

Hope this helps

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score -4):

The index file has become corrupted, but it is easily re-creatable. Just remove it, and re-add the files in your working directory:

```
rm .git/index 
git add .
```